# formatting Access DB Reports record by record

Tags: ms-access, vba

i have a an access report, i want to format the records of this report record by record and this format will be depends of the value of the field according to 1 condition, so how can i go through the report please.

thanks

Comment: any code how your report is structured? (file type etc) What did you tried?

Comment: its simple report, just with 2 fields, many records, depends on simple table, am trying to format each record according to a condition, for examle i have in my report Grade Field, if the value is Ecellent then the BG color to be red and if V.good to be Yellow and so on, the problem that i can not go through this report record by record to ask about the value then to apply the condition the to change the color, thats it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to format a report by the value of one field (column) or control is to use [Conditional Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508986.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but conditional formatting have three conditions only which are not enough, the count of records in my report is more than 3.

Comment: it does not matter how many records you have, three cconditions are something like `[Field1]>4` or so what matters is how many fields (columns) you wish to check. After that, it is possible to extend conditional formatting with code.